# Is there a way to share delicious booksmarks with others in the Firefox plugin?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, delicious

I use delicious bookmarks with the Firefox plugin and it works great.

My book marks follow me around from computer to computer, are easy to save and find (CTRL-D, CTRL-B), etc.

However, it would be **great if I could** **add other people's booksmarks to my firefox delicious plugin so that when I search for bookmarks I search through theirs as well**. Does anyone know if this is possible with the delicious plugin for firefox or if some other social bookmark service offers something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is addressing the **highlighted** part in your question.
You can search for bookmarks in your Delicious Network using

```
http://delicious.com/search?p=SEARCH&chk=&context=network|ID&fr=del_icio_us&lc=1
```

Where `SEARCH` is replaced with your search string and,
`ID` is replaced with your delicious user id.

---

Here is a raw version,

1. Right-click on your toolbar and create a `New Bookmark`

   - Give it some `Name`
   - Copy and paste the string below in the `Location`
   - Replace the `YOURNAME` part with your Delicious username
   - And, remove the two newlines I have kept for readability
   - Save the bookmark
   - Click on it to try

```
javascript:UrlX1='http://delicious.com/search?chk=&context=network|YOURNAME
&fr=del_icio_us&lc=1&p=';SrchQry=prompt('Search%20Delicious%20Network','what');
location.href=UrlX1+SrchQry;
```

When you click on it, a dialogue box will appear with the default search term "what".
You can change this and click `OK` to fire the search.
It will run the search on the logged in Delicious user's `Network`.

You can tweak this further... I am not experienced with java scripts.
Would be glad to learn some corrections in this script.